# Split row in pandas into multiple rows based on the $ symbol

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but before flagging this as a duplicate, none of the answers I found seem to work. I have a dataframe of the form:

```
   category     |     description
   ------------------------------
    puppy              dog$pup
    crappy             cat$pet
    squeeky            animal
    fluffy             dog$pet
```

I want to split the `description` column by the `$` symbol into multiple rows, and obtain something like this:

```
   category     |     description
   ------------------------------
    puppy              dog
    puppy              pup
    crappy             cat
    crappy             pet
    squeeky            animal
    fluffy             dog
    fluffy             pet
```

Sorry for the stupid example, but I hope it illustrates the problem. The last thing I tried is this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['category'], row['description'].split('$'))              
                    for _, row in old_df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

but this returns a :

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is problem missing values, so better is use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for new rows (working for pandas 0.25+):

```
df['description'] = df['description'].str.split('$')
df = df.explode('description')
print (df)
      category description
0        puppy         dog
0        puppy         pup
1       crappy         cat
1       crappy         pet
2      squeeky      animal
3       fluffy         dog
3       fluffy         pet
4  another val         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pre pandas 0.25 answer, think one method here would be an `apply` to perform your split from one into two columns, and then a `melt` to reorganise the data in the structure you want.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{ "category": "puppy", "description": "dog$pup"},
 { "category": "crappy", "description": "cat$pet"},
 { "category": "squeeky", "description": "animal"},
 { "category": "fluffy", "description": "dog$pet"},
]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df["one"], data_df["two"] = zip(*[r[0:2] for r in data_df['description'].apply(lambda x: x.split("$")+ [None] ) ])

data_df[['category','one','two']].melt(id_vars="category")[['category','variable']].sort_values(by=["category", "variable"])
```

[image: DataFrame Screenshot]